# The properties determined by springboot dto are inconsistent with the postman results

Tags: json, spring-boot, dto, mapstruct

the last attribute of my DTO is lAlarmTime, but I use mapstruct to help me convert Entity to DTO, but I use postman to initiate the request and the result is lalarmTime

**DTO**

```java
@Data
public class GetAlarmDto {

    private Long id;

    private String alarmId;

    private String item;

    private String uuid;

    private String criticalPoint;

    private Integer criticalNumber;

    private Integer continuance;

    private Integer coolDownTime;

    private Integer status;
    
    private String lAlarmTime;
```

**Mapstruce Entity -> DTO**

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface GetAlarmMapper extends BaseMapper<GetAlarmDto, Alarm> {

    @Override
    default GetAlarmDto toDto(Alarm entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        GetAlarmDto getAlarmDto = new GetAlarmDto();

        getAlarmDto.setId( entity.getId() );
        getAlarmDto.setAlarmId( entity.getAlarmId() );
        getAlarmDto.setItem(entity.getMonitorItem().getItemName());
        getAlarmDto.setUuid(entity.getVmInstance().getUuid());
        getAlarmDto.setCriticalPoint( entity.getCriticalPoint() );
        getAlarmDto.setCriticalNumber( entity.getCriticalNumber() );
        getAlarmDto.setContinuance( entity.getContinuance() );
        getAlarmDto.setCoolDownTime( entity.getCoolDownTime() );
        getAlarmDto.setStatus( entity.getStatus() );
        getAlarmDto.setLAlarmTime(getLastAlarmTime(entity.getLastAlarmTime()));

        return getAlarmDto;
    }
```

**Postman Result**

[image: Postman Result Picture]

I know it can be achieved through @jsonproperty, but I still want to know why this happens, is it affected by json in the process of serialization or deserialization or

Comment: Not sure, but I think lombok is the reason. You can test it by removing `@Data` and providing getters/setters by your own.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally recommended to follow standard Java naming conventions when defining variable names, which typically use camelCase with the first letter of the first word in lowercase and the first letter of each subsequent word in uppercase.

In your case, the variable name "lAlarmTime" does not follow this convention, as it uses an uppercase "A" in the middle of the variable name. You may want to consider renaming the variable to "lastAlarmTime" to make it consistent with the naming convention.

In addition, the "private" keyword indicates that the variable is only accessible within the class in which it is defined. If you want other classes to be able to access this variable, you may want to consider using a getter and/or setter method or changing the access level to "public".

In your case you can use Something like in the below example!..

```
@Data
public class GetAlarmDto {
    @JsonProperty("YourCustomName") 
    private String lAlarmTime;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but I think my naming is in accordance with the principle of camel case, my first letter is a lowercase l, and the second is an uppercase A